In rhombic Penrose tiling, do the thick rhombi only form finite paths when connected?
In P3 penrose tiling made from thin and thick rhombi, if you connect the thick rhombi together into paths, do they only ever form closed paths? Or is it possible for a path to extend indefinitely?
Additional questions if possible:
Are there any shapes formed that are finite but without pentagonal symmetry?
Are there a finite number of different shapes the paths can form?
Here is an example of some of the "paths" I am referring to:


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

At most two infinite paths of thick rhombs exist in a Penrose tiling, though the periodic points of the substitution (i.e. the rotationally symmetric ones like the one you've included) have all paths being finite. When a path is finite, it has $D_5$ symmetry. This should be in Grünbaum and Shephard's book $[1]$ or even Gardner's original MAA article $[2]$. Actually, I just had a look at Gardner's article (freely available here) and he says:
"Penrose and Conway independently proved that whenever a curve closes, it has a pentagonal symmetry, and the entire region within the curve has a fivefold symmetry. At the most a pattern can have two curves of each color that do not close. In most patterns all curves close"
where here the 'curves' relate to Penrose' original matching rules for the kites and darts, but they also correspond to paths of thick rhombs.
$[1]$ B. Grünbaum and G. C. Shephard, Tilings and Patterns. W. H. Freeman and Company, New York, 1986.
$[2]$ M. Gardner, Penrose Tiles to Trapdoor Ciphers... and the Return of Dr. Matrix. Mathematical Association of America, Oberlin, OH, 1989.

Thanks! Do you know if there are a finite number of shapes the paths can form? I'd assume they can grow arbitrarily large over an infinite tessellation, but if there's a limit then it'd be nice to have a list of them.

They can get arbitrarily large. Just apply the substitution to one and you get a larger one, and it is true that if a patch appears in a Penrose tiling, then so does the substitution of that patch.
